# Items not below and center underneath the nav bar - Responsive Top Navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, flexbox

So following up from my last forums, I was able to get my responsive menu nav bar working. And as well as how I want to center my two items using flex which a lot of people have recommended.

I updated my nav bar because it doesn't have a title in the menu bar so that worked out okay. Now what happened is when I opened it up, it brings down a drop down menu, but my items are not center **and** below my nav. Why is it acting like it "floats" to the right side of the page where it cannot be seen and cut off (especially when viewing it in iPhone mode). Take a look at my screenshot below and my codes and see what is troubling me.

**When the hamburger icon is not tapped**

[image]

**When the hamburger icon is tapped**

[image]

Here is my codes. Run the code snippet or better yet, copy and paste this into your text editor and run it from your browser so you can see what I'm talking about. ***NOTE: The code snippet does what I want to do when you run it but coming from my text editor and browser, it is not doing what I want to do.***

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.summary {
  min-height: 75vh;
  max-width: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profilePicture {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.profileSummary {
  max-width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .summary {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- The navigation menu -->

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="summary">
    <div class="profilePicture">
      <img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.464384650.8618/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="profileSummary">
      Attentive alas because yikes due shameful ouch much kookaburra cantankerously up unbridled far vulnerably climbed aristocratically hired brusque fox said the therefore terrier scallop innocent on goodness mongoose woolly showed insistently and.
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so hard to understand what you mean , or my poor English  :(

Comment: (1) Open nav (2) Menu drops down (3) items not center and beneath menu

Comment: @Cuong Hoang This is where I want my items to be ---> https://i.imgur.com/eySnLM8.jpg

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. I tried in JSFiddle but it seems to be working correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/duvLtsrf/

Comment: but i run the snippet, its alreay centered

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Try copy and paste this into your notepad++ or Atom or whatever text editor you use and open it from your browser.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Don't use JSFiddle, try reproducing it from your own text editor and save it on your desktop and F12 and into iPhone mode and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Still seems to work fine in Chrome. Here's what I pasted into Notepad++ and ran in Chrome: https://pastebin.com/nNNT1M4V

Comment: @AndroidNoobie So I tried copied your code from JSFiddle and did it from my desktop, it works fine, but currently in my project, it seems to be kind of messed up in a way. I created a shareable file so you can download my project and go index.html and view it in mobile mode and you'll see what I'm talking about. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n-aP5ZramtI-8pGeZPr5u4y-aR6zuz4p

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Right click on "Azazel Website" and click on download. Then unzip the file.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Or left click on Azazel Website and download then unzip

Comment: The problem is you have a second `.responsive` class on line 242 of your `main.css`. In it, you're specifying the width to be 24.99%. This is overriding your earlier declared class of the same name. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Hey thanks man! Now that worked! That responsive was actually meant for my portfolio page so I just changed the name in my html to responsivePortfolio and change that line by adding in responsivePortfolio to give it a good meaning and that not screwing it from my index.html.

Comment: No problem. If you want, add the full CSS to your question (from before you made the fix), and I'll post the solution as an answer in case it helps someone else in the future. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code and markup snippet originally posted by this user actually worked as expected. After further investigation, the issue was that the user had a second (duplicate) CSS class that was overriding their earlier CSS.

The first class was in a media query and by itself worked:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

And this class was below it:

```
.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}
```

When the screen width was <= 600 px, the `responsive` class applied to the navbar and the hamburger menu icon appeared. But the second `responsive` class was constraining the width of the expanded menu to 25% of the container, which resulted in the undesired positioning.

In general with problems like this, it's usually a good idea to use the developer tools in your browser to see what CSS rules are being applied to the element in question. You can learn more about [developer tools here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Comment: Hey man you think can help me one more time. Thanks to your help previously, I am making some progress here. Unfortunately, there was some stuff that w3schools don't tell you about and that is switching page and designing page. Stop by over my next forum when you get a chance here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54396946/10332967